# Which user is logged in on the Windows 7 login screen?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

When on the [Windows 7 login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVmGp.png), is there a user logged in?

Since Utilman.exe can be run during that time, it makes sense that a user is currently logged in. Am I completely wrong, and if not, which user is it?

Answer (score 1):

The `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user manages NT system logins with `winlogon`, and other related processes such as `lsass` and `lsm`. `lsass` handles operations in regards to the SAM file which stores local user credentials on a Windows NT system.